# Use video environment from revtex

Tags: revtex, video, newfloat

I want to add a video environment from Revtex class to my thesis. This video environment from Revtex is like the figure environment but a command \setfloatlink{} allows to hyperlink the video 1. (like Fig. 1.) to the video link.

Currently, I use the new float command which doesn't have the hyperlink option for each video I want to add.

I need help to add \setfloatlink to this new float command or import \video environment to my thesis which is of thesis class

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext = los ,
  listname = {List of Videos} ,
  name = video
]{video}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.